# How can I cache dockers images used in google cloud build more effectively than pulling it externally from GCP's container registery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I've already read through https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/optimize-builds/speeding-up-builds

I've made an intermediate image that is stored in the container / artifact registry - it's a pretty large file that is around 5GB.

However if I then use this image in a `FROM northamerica-northeast1-docker.pkg.dev/...blabla` it will still take 4 minutes to download / pull this image? So where on earth is the caching? Is cloud build literally neglecting one of the most useful aspects of docker?

As an alternative using something like gitlab, I could run my own 'build runners' where they would have the image cached locally **on their local diskdrive** which basically means  it's not spending 4+ minutes downloading and extracting the intermediate image.